# Retrieve data from both matching and non matching rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, group-by

Based on query below, you can see that query is returning only the matching rows but I want to retrieve all rows from `USERS` table and `null` in place of non matching.

```
select 
    u.*,
    p.p_title,
    DATE_FORMAT(max(trans.expiry), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') as expiry_date,cn.cell_num 
from (
    select t.e_date as expiry 
    from connections c, trans_tbl t,users u 
    where c.v_lan_id=t.vlanconfk and u.u_id = t.u_id_fk
) AS trans,
users u INNER JOIN connections c on u.u_id=c.u_id_fk
INNER JOIN packages p on c.pkg_id_fk=p.pkg_id
INNER JOIN cell_num cn on u.u_id=cn.u_id_fk
```

Comment: You mean you want to do FULL JOIN?

Comment: Yes, i want all rows from my u.* and not matching rows also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for `left join`s. However your query has several other flaws:

- you are mixing explicit and implicit joins; *always* use explicit joins (with the `on` keyword)
- you have an aggregation function in the `select` clause (`max()`) along with non-aggregated columns, but no `group by` clause
- the purpose of the subquery is rather unclear: it is using the several tables  that are used in the outer query, which makes little sense, and is probably suboptimal

I *suspect* that you could phrase this as:

```
select 
    u.*,
    p.p_title,
    (
        select date_format(max(t.expiry), '%d-%m-%y %h:%i:%s') 
        from trans_tbl t
        where t.vlanconfk = c.v_lan_id and t.u_id_fk = u.u_id
    ) expiry
    cn.cell_num 
from users u 
left join cell_num cn   on cn.u_id_fk  = u.u_id
left join connections c on c.u_id_fk   = u.u_id
left join packages p    on c.p.pkg_id  = pkg_id_fk
```